# Is it possible to trigger a browser's text search in the URL?

Tags: url, browser, sharing

I'm imagining putting a search term in the URL # fragment, like say:
`http://blah/#__text_search__=art`

And when the user pastes this URL into their browser, or clicks on it in e-mail or whatever, it boots up with the search feature activated, like so:

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via the URL as that's part of the website the user is visiting

If it were possible via URL then the `#__text_search__=art` would also be sent to the website.

It may or may not be possible via other means but that will likely be in a browser-dependent way.